# Blank posts being added, as well as the user created post (Django)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

Whenever you click on the **Add a post** button on my forum page, it will instantly add a blank post to the forum, while still adding the user-created post.

Before **Add a post** is clicked:

[image]

After **Add a post** is clicked (but no post details are added):

[image]

I've had a go at changing the view I made for creating posts, but I ended removing the ability to add a post at all! So, wanted to see if anyone had any idea why blank posts were being added, as well as the post the user creates?

View used for adding posts:

```
@login_required
def create_forum_post(request, pk=None):
    """ Create a view that allows us to create a post """

    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk) if pk else None
    if not post:
        post = Post.objects.create(creator_id=request.user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ForumPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save()
        return redirect('forum_post_details', post.pk)
    else:
        form = ForumPostForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'forum_post_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    creator_id = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=timezone.now)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="img", blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```